# Is there a reason not to delete unneeded or empty helpers (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In app/helpers, I have a few ruby files which are just the default module headers/class definitions with no code inside. Is it safe to delete these, or would I need them for any particular reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no harm to deleting the files--you have nothing inside them--I recommend that you keep the files and try to get used to using them. It's a great way of learning how to manage a sizable project!

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to keep these files. You can safely delete all the files that were generated and are just empty placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you might want to not prematurely delete them is if they might be used later.